# can I use static boolean variable as a lock for a synchronized thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I tried to use static boolean variable to lock and unlock two synchronized threads.
So I wrote the following code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        //MyObject lock = new MyObject();
        Thread1 t1 = new Thread1(100,'#');
        Thread1 t2 = new Thread1(100,'*');

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Thread1 extends Thread {

    public static boolean lock;
    int myNum;
    char myChar;

    public Thread1(int num, char c){
        myNum = num;
        myChar = c;
        lock = false;
    }

    public synchronized void run(){
        System.out.println(getName() + " is runing");
        while (Thread1.lock == true){
            System.out.println(getName() + " is waiting");
            try{wait();}
            catch(InterruptedException e){}
        }
        Thread1.lock = true;
        for(int i = 0; i<myNum; i++){
            if(i%10==0)
                System.out.println("");
            System.out.print(myChar);
        }
        Thread1.lock = false;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

probably I am not doing it right, cause only one thread is printing the "mychar" and the other thread is just going into wait() and not waking up when I do the notifyAll().
I thought that this can be a good way to use a static boolean variable for the whole class and than change it every time and call notifyAll() to check this flag in the others objects...

output example:

```
Thread-0 is runing

Thread-1 is runing
Thread-1 is waiting
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
```

Comment: Might as well use a loop instead of Threads, if you want to run Threads serially.

Comment: Classic example to learn multi-threading is to implement Producer/Consumer threads. Producers produce stuff and notify consumers; meanwhile consumers wait after consuming stuff.

Answer (score 4):

**Why it doesn't work**

`notify()` and `wait()` work with the "monitor" of the object they are called on.  In your case, that is the `this`, the particular instance of `Thread1` that is running.

So, when `Thread-0` runs:

- it checks `lock`
- finds it `false`
- it runs the main code
- it calls `notifyAll()` on `this` (which is itself, `Thread-0`).

`Thread-1` runs:

- it checks `lock`
- finds that it is `true`
- and calls `wait()` on `this` (which is itself, `Thread-1`)

Since `Thread-0` calls `notifyAll()` on `this` (which is itself), and `Thread-1` calls `wait()` on `this` (which is *itself*), `Thread-1` is waiting on a different monitor than `Thread-0` is notifying, so it is never released.

**Solution**

If your plan is to just get that code to run sequentially, use this:

```
public class Thread1 extends Thread {

    private static final Object lock = new Object();

    public void run(){
        // non-sequential code
        System.out.println(getName() + " is running");
        synchronized (lock) {
            // this code will be run sequentially by one thread at a time
        }
        // non-sequential code
    }
}
```

Comment: why "public static final Object lock" need to be final?

Comment: @YuvalLevy It doesn't *need* to be, but it gaurentees that a thread cannot change it. If that happened, then objects waiting on the old instance would not be notified by calls to the new object.

Comment: @YuvalLevy also, it should be private, because it has no use outside the `Thread1` class. (Edited)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but this provides negative value, because it has no guarantees and only gives an illusion of safety. There are several issues with this:

1. The variable is non-volatile, as such changes from one thread may not be visible to the other.
2. Your locking is not atomic. Hence what could happen is both threads can pass the while loop, and then both set the boolean to true.
3. `notifyAll()` wakes up all threads waiting *on the object instance*. And since each thread is waiting on itself as the monitor, they are not getting woken up.

There are plenty of good locking mechanisms in Java - try the ones in the concurrency package (Though in your case a simple synchronized block is enough). If you insist on using a boolean for a lock, you would need to:

1. Make a static *final* `AtomicBoolean` as you signaler (non final is fine as long as you don't change it and guarantee visibility)
2. Use `compareAndSet` as your looping/locking condition so that access is atomic.
3. `Wait()` on the `AtomicBoolean` so that the threads share the monitor they are waiting on (and `notifyAll()` on it as well).

Comment: can you please explain issue number 3 more? If the thread is waiting on itself as the monitor why it will not woke up?

Comment: Threads wait on object instances. In this case you have 2 instances: `t1` and `t2`. Thread 1 waits on `t1`. Thread 2 works, and when done notifies everything that is waiting on the object that notify is called against, i.e. `t2`. However, nothing is waiting on `t2` (`t1` and `t2` are different objects), hence nothing wakes up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simpler way to synchronize the threads.

```
class Thread1 extends Thread {

    private static final Object lock = new Object();
    int myNum;
    char myChar;

    public Thread1(int num, char c){
        myNum = num;
        myChar = c;
    }

    public void run(){
        System.out.println(getName() + " is runing");
        synchronized(lock) {
            for(int i = 0; i<myNum; i++){
                if(i%10==0)
                    System.out.println("");
                System.out.print(myChar);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eh, hasn't Jamie already provided an almost identical piece of code, along with some explanations (and also mentioned briefly in my answer)? Also, you don't need a notifyAll on the lock.